# Are there improvements to enable spending of change funds faster?

Tags: address, change

Currently when you send coins from your address to another address. The change funds are locked in a "unconfirmed" state. This is a big UX issue as I can't spend my coins again and have to wait a few minutes. How many exactly? Is there a proposed improvement to fix this major user experience issue?